# Mobile game, cross platform leaderboard / challenges

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-play-games, gamekit

I am developing a small word game as a side project and chose Flutter to release the game for both Android and iOS. I am able to use flutter packages (e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/games_services) to integrate with Google Play Games and Apple Game Kit but I think this doesn't allow e.g. to create a cross platform leaderboard, but iOS and Android players see their separate scores.

Options I found:

- Use Google Play Service, also for Apple users (seems to have some issues though and not work for iOS users seamlessly)
- I have looked at quite some smaller games that are using their own leaderboard implementations and have seen some small projects that implement one with Flutter and Firebase (e.g. https://github.com/fateh491989/leaderboard).
- I also found 2 other leaderboard services (https://github.com/omgwtfgames/omgleaderboards and https://leaderboards.io), not sure what the advantage is of those vs using firebase.

Before I go down the route of creating a simple scoring / leader board using fire base, I was hoping to find someone here who looked into this as well. Is there a way to use the Google and Apple services, yet see stats x-platforms?  I would prefer this, also hoping to give users a more integrated experience and maybe also gaining new users through this.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't make a single leaderboard for both platforms, unless you load both leaderboards data, you sort it and then display it inside your game. But if you're going to use Firebase, there are two sign-in options, one with Google Play Games and another one with Game Center, so you will be able to give your users the

> more integrated experience

you just mencioned.